# Uncaught (in promise) Error for fetch function

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I am currently working on fetching data to display multiple graphs and my fetchGraphData function is not working correctly. I receive the error "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.  I understand this a problem with my promise is it because its being rejected or that it is receiving data in the json that shouldnt be there? I am fairly new to Javascript and still learning so any insight or suggestions are welcome.

```
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: 'START_ADDING_GRAPHDATA_REQUEST'})

        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            let graph = {
                id: parseInt(data.id),
                name: data.name,
                info_url: data.info_url,
                screenshot_url: data.screenshot_url
            }
            dispatch({ type: 'ADD_GRAPHDATA', graph })
        })
    }
}
```

```
export default function graphsReducer(state= [], action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        // this is where the fetch get request grabs graphs when they are loaded 
        case 'START_ADDING_GRAPHDATA_REQUEST':
            console.log("fetching inner graph")
            return state
```

Comment: What's the `console.log` show? Sounds like the result isn't JSON, but HTML (hence the `<` which is usually the first character in an HTML doc)

Comment: My log shows my reducers console.log where it would be using my graph reducer to display it.

Comment: Whenever you have an error, search for the error. For instance [How to fix “Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0” ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58376907/215552) may give some clue. Perhaps the `url` is incorrect and you're getting a 404 HTML page in the response? `fetch` does not reject the promise based on status code.